# Match regex : Extract Number only between space

Tags: regex

I have string text as

```
17-2018-04-04 17:31:00,289 20055001        test@abc.com
```

How can i extract number `20055001`.

I am using this `\s\d+(?=\s++)` , but i am getting space between number.

Comment: Language? C#? JavaScript?

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)`

Comment: `[0-9]+(?=\s{2,})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same way you used a positive-lookahead for the spaces after the number, you should use a positive-lookbehind for the spaces before

```
(?<=\s)\d+(?=\s++)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8RgFMe/1)**